# Highlight current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a website, and I was tired of copy/pasting headers and footers to each page, because when you than need to change one letter, you have to change it on all pages using that header/footer. So I 'copied' a function I learnt from Laravel, partials.

I write the HTML of the header in one file, and than load that to the page using PHP.

Code of my header:

```
<div class="header">                                                                           
    <div class="header-wrapper">                                                               
        <a href="index.php">                                                                   
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" />                                         
        </a>                                                                                   
        <ul>                                                                                   
            <li><a onload="highlight(this);" href="index.php">Home</a></li>                    
            <li><a onload="highlight(this);" href="over.php">Over ons</a></li>                 
            <li><a onload="highlight(this);" href="catalogus.php">Onze machines</a></li>       
            <li><a onload="highlight(this);" href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>           
            <li><a onload="highlight(this);" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>               
        </ul>                                                                                  
    </div>                                                                                     
</div>                                                                                         

<script>                                                                                       
    //Highlight current                                                                        
    function highlight(obj) {                                                                  
        var page = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);        
        if (page == obj.getAttribute("href")) {                                                
            obj.classList.add("current");                                                      
        }                                                                                      

        alert(page);                                                                           
        alert(obj.getAttribute("href"));                                                       
    }                                                                                          

</script>
```

CSS:

```
.current {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And the header is included in pages like this:

```
<?php
 //Include header
 $f = fopen("partial/header.html", "r");
 echo fread($f, 4096);
?>
```

This is working, the only problem is that I want to show the current page the user is on in the header. This by just underlining the current page-name in the header.

The function highlight() is working, but the onload isn't working.
It seems that the anchor-tag isn't supported by the onLoad-function.

How would I fix this? How to execute the highlight()-function on each anchor tag onLoad?

Javascript and JQuery allowed, am not using  a framework.

Comment: In a function attached to `window.onload`, get a list of the anchors, iterate and call `highlight` on each of them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not using Jquery 'll keep it plain javascript

```
 var page = location.pathname.substring(
    location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
 );

document.querySelectorAll('li > a').forEach(el => {
  if (page == el.getAttribute('href')) {
    el.classList.add('current');
  }
});
```

To explain what is going on here we're selecting all anchor tags in a list item. I'd suggest giving the list a `class` so you can identify it better in the javascript like so.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.nav a')
```

and add the class to the HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mike for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to fix it with a bit of JQuery.

```
<script>        
    //Highlight current
    function highlight(obj) {
        var page = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1); 
        if (page == obj.getAttribute("href")) {
            obj.classList.add("current");
        }
    }           

    //Launch highlight function on document load
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".header-wrapper ul li a").each(function() {
            highlight(this);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note: you still have to handle that www.mywebsite.com/ won't work, because it hasn't a filename in the url like www.mywebsite.con/**index.php** has.